# Call Dialog: Not work on API 10

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a class that extends Dialog Fragment. To show this Dialog use this code

```
DialogClass myDialog = new DialogClass();
myDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
```

In my manifest I like minSdkVersion APIs 10 and in fact eclipse tells me

- Call requires API level 11 (current min is 10): android.preference.PreferenceActivity#getFragmentManager
- Call requires API level 11 (current min is 10): android.app.DialogFragment#show

How can I do to show the Dialog using the API 10?

Comment: Does eclipse shows this as an error and prevent you from building?

Answer (score 3):

You must use SupportFragmentManager instead of FragmentManager

Answer (score 0):

Use getSupportFragmentManager() and import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

Comment: Eclipse says The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener(){}

Comment: Do for example MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: Extend FragmentActivity

Comment: And how can i use getActivity() ? The method getActivity() is undefined for the type myClass

Comment: I'm in a PreferenceActivity and if i extends FragmentActivity i've error when i findPreference with a similar code
        pref = (Preference) this.findPreference("myPref"); how can i solve?

Comment: I think you need to make another class that extends FragmentActivity and handles the dialog.