# use getSupportFragmentManager in PreferenceActivity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I'm using a PreferenceActivity and I need to use the method `getSupportFragmentManager()` to show a dialog. I have a code like this

```
myClassDialog dia = new myClassDialog();
dia.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
```

Eclipse gives me this error:

> The method `getSupportFragmentManager()` is undefined for the type new `Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener(){}`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call Dialog: Not work on API 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523119/call-dialog-not-work-on-api-10)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922906/is-it-possible-to-launch-a-dialogfragment-from-a-preference-in-a-preferenceactiv

Comment: You just asked this 34 min ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523119/call-dialog-not-work-on-api-10) question and got an answer. Why not take some time to try to find the solution yourself and learn?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are doing this inside a OnPreferenceClickListener instance, and that class has not his method.

Use PreferenceFragment instead of PrerenceActivity.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you copied some code, and you are adapting it, and asking here to solve every problem. If you go that way, you will go crazy. The way you should do it, is read - understand - (try - fail - take your time to understand ) * many times - and then ask. you will learn a lot and will do much better programs.

To get started, you can read some code here:

[Android Developer - Reference -  PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html)

Or read a complete guide here:

[Android Developer - Api Guides - UI - Settings](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

If you go on with this, and have any further problem, don't hesitate to come back with any question and i will be glad to help you out!

Answer (score -1):

You can use getFragmentManager() is available with all activities.

> ```
> FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
> DialogFragment newFragment = CustomDialogFragment.newInstance("", "");
> newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
> ```

Comment: The question is about gettingSupportFragmentManager()